# Can't figure out how to have my javafx jar file run on a website using the java web start tool

Tags: java, xml, jar, server

I have been struggling for hours with this issue. I am currently writing the jnlp code but I keep getting this error. Can someone please help me out!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 

<!-- JNLP File for Sequence —-> 
<jnlp  spec="1.0+" xmlns:jfx="http://localhost:8080" 
    codebase="http://localhost:8080"    
    href="Sequence.jnlp"> 
    <information> 
        <title>Sequence V1.0
    </title> 
        <vendor>Ben and Cam
    </vendor> 
       <description>Sequence Application by Cam Weston and Ben Citrin
    </description> 
    <homepage href="http://localhost:8080/sequence.html"/>
       <description kind="short">Sequence Application uses several custom classes 
            plus several standard ones
    </description> 
       <offline-allowed /> 
     </information>

     <resources> 
       <jar href="Sequence2.jar"/> 
    <j2se version="1.6+"
        href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se"/> 
    <jfx:javafx-runtime version="2.1+" 
            href="http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/GetFile/
                    javafx-latest/windows-i586/javafx2.jnlp"/>
     </resources> 
     <application-desc main-class="MainWindow"/> 
</jnlp>
```

Error is : org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 6; columnNumber: 6; The value of attribute "codebase" associated with an element type "jnlp" must not contain the '<' character.

Okay update I changed to ascii quotes and am now getting this error 
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 30; columnNumber: 8; XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:177)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1438)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:904)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.endEntity(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:563)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityManager.endEntity(XMLEntityManager.java:1399)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.load(XMLEntityScanner.java:1814)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanData(XMLEntityScanner.java:1292)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanComment(XMLScanner.java:778)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanComment(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1039)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:904)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:510)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:848)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:777)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1213)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:643)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:327)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.xml.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Comment: What error? Please add a full stacktrace to your question.

Comment: Replace all smart quotes (curly quotes) with ASCII quotes in your .jnlp file.  Meaning, change `“` and `”` to `"`.

Comment: Thank you, now I'm getting: Error: Could not parse launch file. Error at line 30.

Comment: It is a JavaFX program and my end goal is to put it on my web server (currently running Apache Tomcat 8.0) with Java Web Start